# SQL Server to Oracle through DB Trigger

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want to integrate the SQL Server 2014 database Express edition with an Oracle 10g database. For that I have made a linked server which is working fine. And from New Query Window if I query or insert data into linked database (Oracle 10g) it works fine.

But when I try to insert data into that linked database (Oracle 10g) from DB trigger of a table in SQL Server (Table structure on both side is same) I get an error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORC1" returned message "New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator. ".
>
> (0 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 2, Procedure TR_CheckOutType, Line 26
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORCL" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
>
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

32-bit SQL Server Express addition is running on 32bit OS of Windows 7 pro and the Oracle 10g database is running on 32bit Windows server 2008 machine.

MSDTC service in on for both servers. (was off first, but I made it on by reading another theed on this site)

Please help

Comment: Trigger is the last place where your database db sync proces...

Comment: Have you configured MSDTC on your windows machine?

Comment: Yes the MSDTC  service in on for both servers. (was off first, but I made it on by reading another theed on this site)